# Receiving data with Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a search page that shows several different criteria that a user may filter by. Each user will likely wish to search the same thing each time s/he uses the application thus, each `User` entity contains a default value for each field.

```
public class User
{
    public string name ...
    public string DefaultCriteria1
    public string DefaultCriteria2
    ...
}
```

My goal is to create a button on the search page which on clicking, will retrieve the current user in some form (XML? JSON?) and set all the values as appropriate. I am new to jQuery and am unsure of what needs to occur for these desired effects to take place.

As for an answer, here are the things I am looking for

1. How does jQuery call an action?
2. What format does the action return data in? If there is a choice, what are they and what are some pros/cons for each?
3. How do I receive this data using jQuery and parse it.

**EDIT**:
The answer I desire are more high level, not specific code. For example, "jQuery executes a GET/POST request to the action...", "I would use JSON in this case because...", "XML would be beneficial in xyz case", etc.

Comment: Have you looked up any tutorials on this topic? What have you tried?

Comment: Jquery can retrieve data through AJAX and even parse JSON. Just do $.getJSON() or $.ajax() (look up on the jquery docs for more info)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Perhaps providing my `User` class was a mistake. I am not looking for an answer providing me with the code I need, but rather an analysis of whether or not my direction was correct and if I was missing any gaps. I was hoping to receive high level answers which consisted of how these calls work and via what technologies. I will update my question to better suit my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Calling an action should be no different than a normal page request.  jQuery has a lot of methods that do this built in, but the base one is `$.ajax`
2. The data is returned in whatever format you want it to return.  There are not necessarily pros/cons, just whatever works best for your needs.  I think that JSON would work best here.  You can control this on the server side, but also with jQuery by using the `dataType` option to `$.ajax`.
3. As an example:

---

```
 $.getJSON('/action').done(function (data) {
    $("#DefaultCriteria1").val(data.DefaultCriteria1);
 });
```